# Is there a general way to solve double integrals if they are not separable?

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral

For example, consider:

$$I = \int_{z=0}^{d}\int_{r=0}^{a}\frac{zr}{\sqrt{z^2+r^2}} \ dr \ dz $$

Without the square root term, this would be a simple integral. With it, I can't find a way to solve it. Is there a general way to solve integrals with non-separable terms?

Comment: Expressions of the form $z^2+r^2$ are just begging for a polar substitution. Start there, and be sure to carefully change the bounds of the integral and the differentials appropriately.

Comment: Or, you can just solve the inner integral in the same way as $$\int x(c+x^2)^{-1/2}\, dx$$

Comment: Your terminology is not standard here. By "separable" you mean that the function you're integrating is of the form $f(r,z) = g(r)h(z)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, of separable variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double integrals which are "separable" are actually the exception - most are not.  The general idea is that you evaluate a double integral as an integral of an integral.  You also have to remember that in $\int\cdots dx$ there are implied brackets, so your integral needs to be considered as
$$I = \int_{z=0}^{d}\left(\int_{r=0}^{a}\frac{zr}{\sqrt{z^2+r^2}} \ dr\right) \ dz\ .$$
Now you do the "inner" integral, treating $r$ as the variable and $z$ as a constant, so that it is not much different from
$$\int_{r=0}^{a}\frac{5r}{\sqrt{5^2+r^2}} \ dr\ .$$
Once you have completed this integral, there will be no $r$ in the answer (because you have substituted $r=0$ and $r=a$) but there will still be a $z$.  So to complete the job you have to integrate
$$I=\int_{z=0}^{d} \hbox{previous answer}(z)\,dz\ .$$

Comment: Ah, thank you. This makes sense.